# Ubuntu 18.04 with dual monitors issue

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors and every time I boot up my system with the second monitor turned ***off***, all my icons on the desktop are squashed to the very right (see screen shot).

When I turn the second monitor ***on***, all icons are moved to that monitor whereas this is not my main monitor, my main monitor is the first monitor where I always keep my icons.

It's so annoying. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: My work around is to right click on the desktop and uncheck "align icons". Then right click again and check "align icons".

Comment: LOL are you kidding me? :D

Comment: Star Wars rule number 1: *Never kid a Jedi*

Comment: This is probably one of the reasons why Gnome for now dropped legacy desktop icon support through the  file manager: the code is old and does not scale well in some situations with modern hardware and multiple monitors.